# Custom sort specifiers in meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a collection in Meteor that's basically a linked list on the objects' ids. I'd like to sort the objects from head to tail.

According to Meteor's [documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#sortspecifiers) the sort specifiers you can use are just ascending and descending on a key. Is there a way to sort a linked list or make my own custom sort specifier?

Answer (score 1):

It's application level problem. I don't think Meteor or even Mongodb will support this natively soon, and I think you can fetch the Collection, and then do it by yourself (May Underscore.js helps).

Comment: Correct, this is a MongoDB question, and it looks like [MongoDB can't sort by an arbitrary function at the database-level](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%7B%7Bsort%28%29%7D%7D) so you'll have to fetch the objects then sort on your own.